# Dependency conflict when trying to install Yesod?

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I'm trying to follow the following Yesod tutorial http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Yesod-tutorial-for-newbies/, but I'm getting the following error when trying to do `cabal-dev install`

```
cabal-dev install -v
/usr/bin/cabal --numeric-version
/usr/local/bin/ghc-pkg --version
Using ghc-pkg 7.6.3
/usr/bin/cabal --version
/usr/bin/cabal --config-file=/home/pedro/HaskellPlaying/TestApi/MyApiTest/cabal-dev/cabal.config install --verbose=2
Reading available packages...
Choosing modular solver.
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: MyApiTest-0.0.0 (user goal)
trying: fast-logger-2.0.0/installed-a9d... (dependency of MyApiTest-0.0.0)
next goal: warp (dependency of MyApiTest-0.0.0)
rejecting: warp-2.0.1, 2.0.0.1, 2.0.0 (conflict: MyApiTest => warp>=1.3 &&
<1.4)
trying: warp-1.3.10.1
next goal: wai (dependency of warp-1.3.10.1)
rejecting: wai-2.0.0 (conflict: warp => wai>=1.3 && <1.5)
trying: wai-1.4.1
next goal: wai-extra (dependency of MyApiTest-0.0.0)
rejecting: wai-extra-2.0.0.1, 2.0.0 (conflict: MyApiTest => wai-extra>=1.3 &&
<1.4)
rejecting: wai-extra-1.3.4.6, 1.3.4.5, 1.3.4.4, 1.3.4.3, 1.3.4.2, 1.3.4.1,
1.3.4, 1.3.3.2, 1.3.3.1, 1.3.3, 1.3.2.4 (conflict:
fast-logger==2.0.0/installed-a9d..., wai-extra => fast-logger>=0.2 && <0.4)
rejecting: wai-extra-1.3.2.3, 1.3.2.2, 1.3.2.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.1.1, 1.3.1,
1.3.0.5, 1.3.0.4, 1.3.0.3, 1.3.0.2, 1.3.0.1, 1.3.0 (conflict: wai==1.4.1,
wai-extra => wai>=1.3 && <1.4)
rejecting: wai-extra-1.2.0.6, 1.2.0.5, 1.2.0.4, 1.2.0.3, 1.2.0.2, 1.2.0.1,
1.2.0, 1.1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.4.6, 0.4.5.2, 0.4.5.1, 0.4.5, 0.4.4,
0.4.3, 0.4.2, 0.4.1.2, 0.4.1.1, 0.4.0.3, 0.4.0.2, 0.4.0.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.3,
0.3.2.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.4.2, 0.2.4.1, 0.2.4, 0.2.3, 0.2.2.2,
0.2.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.0, 0.1.3.1, 0.1.3, 0.1.2.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.1, 0.1.0,
0.0.0.2, 0.0.0.1, 0.0.0 (conflict: MyApiTest => wai-extra>=1.3 && <1.4)
```

I'm new cabal so I don't really understand the problem, though it seems like the issue is that someone wants wai-extra to be one version while something else wants it to be something else.

Could someone tell me what the issue is and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Just in case if you haven't thought, you can install yesod using your package manager. (`sudo apt-get install yesod`)

Comment: Yeah but the tutorial says to install stuff with cabal. The .cabal file that states the dependencies can only be run with cabal, no? And mixing managers (apt-get with cabal) is probably bad, unless someone tells me otherwise.

Comment: @sibi- I don't think he is trying to install yesod, but rather install/deploy a yesod project....

Comment: Can you try "cabal update", and repeat?  This may solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you have a mismatch between the version of the scaffolded site and the version of Yesod you have installed. If you run `yesod version`, you can see which version of the scaffolded site you have generated.

Your best bet is to install the newest version of both the `yesod-bin` package and the `yesod-platform` package. You can find instructions for this on the [Yesod quick start page](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart), but it's essentially the command:

```
cabal install yesod-bin yesod-platform
```

Then try generating a new scaffolding, and you should hopefully be good-to-go.

Comment: It looks like that was the issue. I scrapped the old project, cleaned everything and downloaded the yesod-platform and `yesod init` a new project. Everything went well after that.